# Trouble with model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a search with custom data in this action here below,

```
def number_price(user_id,to)
    user = User.find(user_id)   
    prices = Price.where(user_id: user_id)
    price.each do |price|
      if to =~ /^(price.prefix)/
        return price."price_#{user_currency.downcase}"
      else
        return DefaultPrices."price_#{user_currency.downcase}"
      end    
end
```

But i having an error with this request here on the line;

```
return price."price_#{user_currency.downcase}"
```

Any idea how i can improve this and make it work.. i have a feeling it something silly..
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your model looks like

But I guess you are trying to achieve dynamic function call which can be done by

```
return price.send("price_#{user_currency.downcase}")
```

Or

```
return eval "price.price_#{user_currency.downcase}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [public_send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send) instead [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) because `public_send` invoke only public method on class instance:

```
class Foo
private
  def bar
    puts "Hi!"
  end
end
=> nil
=> f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007f83e3813af8>
=> f.bar
=> #NoMethodError: private method `bar' called for #<Foo:0x007f83e3813af8>
=> f.send(:bar)
Hi!
=> nil
class Baz
 def bor
   puts "Ho!"
  end
end
=> nil
=> s = Baz.new
=> #<Baz:0x007f83e2429da8>
=> s.bor
Ho!
=> nil
=> s.public_send(:bor)
Ho!
=> nil
```